# Doing timeseries analysis of Global Forest Change (Hansen) for years 2010-2020 using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am struggling to do a timeseries analysis where I want to plot the yearly losses for the period 2010-2020. But it seems there is only the possibility to compare the lossyear to the treecover of the year 2000?

I have included my code in which I switched off the country input and changed it into using a custom geometry.

```
var geometry_area = selected.geometry().area()
var geometry_areaHA = ee.Number(geometry_area).divide(10000).round()
print(geometry_areaHA, 'geometry area (ha)')

// Selected country (e.g. Bolivia).
//var country = 'Canada';
// Canopy cover percentage (e.g. 10%).
var cc = ee.Number(10);
// Minimum forest area in pixels (e.g. 6 pixels, ~ 0.5 ha in this example).
var pixels = ee.Number(8.8);
// Minimum mapping area for tree loss (usually same as the minimum forest area).
var lossPixels = ee.Number(6);

// Load country features from Large Scale International Boundary (LSIB) dataset.
//var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
//var selected = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', ee.String(country)));

var gfc2021 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2021_v1_9');

var canopyCover = gfc2021.select(['treecover2000']);

var canopyCover10 = canopyCover.gte(cc).selfMask();

// Use connectedPixelCount() to get contiguous area.
var contArea = canopyCover10.connectedPixelCount();
// Apply the minimum area requirement.
var minArea = contArea.gte(pixels).selfMask();

var prj = gfc2021.projection();
var scale = prj.nominalScale();
Map.addLayer(minArea.reproject(prj.atScale(scale)), {
    palette: ['#96ED89']
}, 'tree cover: >= min canopy cover & area (light green)');

// CALCULATE THE TREE COVER AREA (HA). USE PIXELAREA() TO GET THE 
// VALUE OF EACH PIXEL IN SQUARE METRES, DIVIDE BY 10,000 TO CONVERT 
// TO HECTARE, AND SUM OVER THE RESULT FOR A MEASURE OF AREA

var forestArea = minArea.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000);
var forestSize = forestArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: selected.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
print(
    'Year 2000 tree cover (ha) \nmeeting minimum canopy cover and \nforest area thresholds \n ',
    forestSize.get('treecover2000'));
    

var pixelCount = minArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: selected.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
var onePixel = forestSize.getNumber('treecover2000')
    .divide(pixelCount.getNumber('treecover2000'));
var minAreaUsed = onePixel.multiply(pixels);
print('Minimum forest area used (ha)\n ', minAreaUsed);

var treeLoss = gfc2021.select(['lossyear']);
var treeLoss18 = treeLoss.eq(18).selfMask(); // TREE LOSS IN YEAR 2018
// Select the tree loss within the derived tree cover
// (>= canopy cover and area requirements).
var treecoverLoss01 = minArea.and(treeLoss18).rename('loss2018').selfMask();

// Create connectedPixelCount() to get contiguous area.
var contLoss = treecoverLoss01.connectedPixelCount();
// Apply the minimum area requirement.
var minLoss = contLoss.gte(lossPixels).selfMask();

var lossArea = minLoss.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000);
var lossSize = lossArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: selected.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
print(
    'Year 2018 tree loss (ha) \nmeeting minimum canopy cover and \nforest area thresholds \n ',
    lossSize.get('loss2018'));
    
// Unmask the derived loss.
var minLossUnmask = minLoss.unmask();
// Switch the binary value of the loss (0, 1) to (1, 0).
var notLoss = minLossUnmask.select('loss2018').eq(1);
// Combine the derived tree cover and not-loss with 'and'.
var treecoverLoss01 = minArea.and(notLoss).selfMask();

var contArea01 = treecoverLoss01.connectedPixelCount();
var minArea01 = contArea01.gte(pixels);
Map.addLayer(minArea01.reproject(prj.atScale(scale)), {
    palette: ['#168039']
}, 'tree cover 2018 (gain not considered) (light green)');

var forestArea01 = minArea01.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000);
var forestSize01 = forestArea01.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: selected.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
print(
    'Year 2018 tree cover (ha) \nmeeting minimum canopy cover and \nforest area thresholds \n ',
    forestSize01.get('treecover2000'));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot conduct a formal timeseries analysis on this data because it is binomial and does not meet the assumption of a stochastic process. You can look at pair-wise differences and such but, cannot derive a true trend, even if translated to focal proportions.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans but there is yearly tree loss data right? So I should be able to plot tree loss 2017, tree loss 2018, tree loss 2019 etc.

Comment: Absolutely, you can create a plot of loss/gain but, this is not a timeseries analysis. Timeseries are a specific type of statistical model (eg., autoregressive AR(I), ARIMA, forecasting, ...) with both data and model assumptions. So, when you say "timeseries analysis" it means some specific and not just that you are exploring and visualizing data. Now, that said there are many ways that you can leverage binomial forest/non-forest with one plotting the loss/gain by year. However statistically, you are back to pair-wise comparisons. You can looks at structural change as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're after something like this?

```
var aoi = Map.getBounds(true)

var lossyear = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2021_v1_9')
  .select('lossyear')

var features = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(lossyear
  .addBands(ee.Image.pixelArea())
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted().group(), 
    geometry: aoi, 
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  })
  .get('groups')
).map(function (dict) {
  return ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(dict))
    .select(['group', 'sum'], ['year', 'area'])
}))
  
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: features, 
  xProperty: 'year', 
  yProperties: 'area'
})

print(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6737bedbc0221eb517c2214928f64a4b